# How is '2'+'2'-'2'= 20 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, math

I was just randomly playing around JavaScript. 
The `'2'+'2'-'2'` input I given to it.

and the output is surprisingly `20`.

```js
console.log('2'+'2'-'2');
```

Now I am not getting it.

**Does anyone explain is to me Why it is like this? How can be output of this equal to `20`?**

Comment: with strings ... '2' + '2' = '22' ... '22' - '2' - because `-` only works with Numbers, both values are "coerced" to Numbers, and 22-2 = 20

Comment: + can be used for string concatenation so you end up with '2' + '2' = '22'; - is only used for arithmetic so 22 - 2 = 20

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`+` is both concatenation and addition. If any of the arguments are not numeric, then it's concatenation. Thus, `'2' + '2'` is `'22'` - just like `"foo" + "bar"` are `"foobar"`, and just like `3 + {}` is `"3[object Object]"`.

`-` is only subtraction. No matter what its arguments are, they are coerced to numbers. Thus, `'22' - '2'` is evaluated as `22 - 2`, which is 20.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript performs string concatenation when find `+`. So the first "2" and second "2" makes "22".

But when performing subtraction (`-`) on strings, **coercion** happens. So the resulted "22" **coerced** to number `22` and final "2" **coerced** to number `2`. Finally subtracts `2` from `22` to result `20`.

For More: [Coercion](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-js-coercion-ff5684475bfc)

Step by step evaluation:

`'2' + '2' - '2'` To

`'22' - '2'` To

`22 - 2` To `20`

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism at play in JavaScript is called [`coercion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion).

The `+` sign in JavaScript can either perform string concatenation, or arithmetic addition. So how does JavaScript choose which action to perform?

In case both arguments (on either side of the +) are strings, JavaScript performs a concatenation.

```js
console.log(2 + 2); // 4
console.log('2' + '2'); // '22'
```

The minus sign however has only one meaning: the arithmetic subtraction.

So JavaScript has only one way to interpret `'22' - 2` which is to subtract 2 from '22'. But of course '22' is not a number, so JavaScript first forces it ("coerces" it) into a number.

The real operation performed is `22 - 2`, which easily computes to `20`, the result you observe.